# get an access code from the doorkeeper gem

Tags: oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

when we request by click on authorize.........

request send to the

```
http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=57070f3927deea2d38c50afa042ae0o9u0c539e4d45a79e203cd66d286f9ec8e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code
```

the response come

```
http://localhost:3000/?code=1560b332321dd2obc99ed3411c78614ce0d59c90e9264c87b7f2f179441d6b4e
```

now i hve to copy the "code" put in console like below code.....

```
app_id = "57070f3927deea2d38c50afa042ae0o9u0c539e4d45a79e203cd66d286f9ec8e"
secret = "1dbd541132ca2bdeb9fe83b41d24490b2be445c30fd1856e5914f6d343c4a71b"
client = OAuth2::Client.new(app_id, secret, site: "http://localhost:3000/")
client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: callback)
access = client.auth_code.get_token('1560b332321dd2obc99ed3411c78614ce0d59c90e9264c87b7f2f179441d6b4e', redirect_uri: callback)
access.token
```

this how the access_token is generated...

is there a better way to get the access code from the dookeeper

Answer (score 0):

This is standard way described by [oauth2.0 specification](http://goo.gl/XkoanG) for autorization code based retrieval of access token. There are other ways like implicit, password and client credentials. Check out the details in RFC and try it with Doorkeeper.